# Hatless in Sea-hat-le

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2014

Oh. MY. GODS!

Hats don't show in mouse-over blow-ups of profile pictures in the recent reviews showcase.

Before mouse-over:

[image]

So far so good. Mousing over:

[image]

My life is temporarily ruined.

Comment: Oh, the humanity...

Comment: I think you need an ["Eeek!"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83625/203888).

Comment: @rgettman: Fixed.

Comment: I will be holding my breath until this is fully fixed

Comment: As of now, the mouse-over hats appear in posts, but not in the reviews page.

Comment: I'm switching to expertsexchange until this is resolved.

Comment: @tristan Now we *know* you are lying...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hats. Hats hats hats.

Hats hats hats, *hats* hats hats hats hats. Hats hats:

- Hats hats hats (hats; hats hats)
- Hats
- Hats hats – hats hats hats.

Hats.

Comment: +hats.  Hats hats hats-hats hats.  :)

Comment: [James while John hat hat hat hat hat hat hat hat hat hat hat a better effect on the teacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett [Hat hat Hat hat hat hat Hat hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo).